# MSMQ: Why can't I retrieve queue details from a remote private queue?

Tags: c#, msmq

I'm trying to retrieve details about messages in a remote private queue, but I continue to get a MessageQueueException "Invalid queue path name".  I am able to retrieve a list of private queues using MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine, however, when I try to view any of the details of the queues returned I get the exception.

```cs
var msmqQueues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(serverName);
msmqQueues[0].CreateCursor();  // Throws MessageQueueException "Invalid queue path name"
msmqQueues[0].Label; // also Throws MessageQueueException "Invalid queue path name"
```

Strangely, the GetPrivateQueuesByMachine call seems to work as msmqQueues has the correct number of items in it and I can access the .Path property of them (and it looks like a typical FormatName path - "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:SERVERNAME\private$\QUEUENAME").

Answer (score 0):

A lot of functionally and properties of private queues in workgroup mode is not available remotely, just the nature of the beast. Most methods and properties should have a matrix on their msdn pages outlining availability, eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.label.aspx